# Designing an electromagnet

Tags: electromagnetism, solenoid, magnetics

I'm new to magnetics and apologize in advance if any of these questions are too basic. I'm looking to build an electromagnet array to move around an object placed on top of the array. Something similar to the image below. Based on my understanding the number of windings the core material, and the amount of current and frictional force to overcome define the strength of the magnet.

1. Would this be the right formula to calculate the force of the electromagnet with N turns, current I at distance D from it's center F = (N * I)^2 * μ0 * A / (2 * D^2)?
2. How do you decide between bigger core cross-secttional area vs having multiple layers of windings? (From the image it looks like there are multiple layers of windings around the core with N turns each)
3. Would this be a good core to use, bit unsure if this is even the right type. https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/fair-rite-products-corp/4077374711/8600016

[image]

Comment: Ferrite materials are non-electrically conductive to prevent eddy currents when AC is applied. You are using DC (or very low frequency AC), so this doesn't apply. A simple iron rod will probably work. What is more important is that your core doesn't become permanently magnetized. I don't know how to determine this.

Comment: Bump for reach...